# PostgreSQL logging logs the same query multiple times

Tags: postgresql, logging

I have just enabled my PostgreSQL 12 instance on Windows 10 to log queries executed by a framework I use.
I've changed the following lines in `postgresql.conf`:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_file_mode = 0640
log_min_duration_statement = 1000
log_duration = on
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p] %q%u@%d (%c) '
log_statement = 'all'
```

Then restarted the service and executed `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`

I can see the query being logged, but it is logged multiple times:

```
2021-04-22 15:16:58.955 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.013 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:58.955 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di S_4: BEGIN
2021-04-22 15:16:58.955 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.036 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:58.955 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.098 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:58.955 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.170 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:58.955 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:58.955 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:58.965 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.750 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:58.990 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:58.990 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.001 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.423 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.028 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.028 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.041 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 13.008 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.065 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.065 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.076 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.359 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.099 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.099 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.110 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.689 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.134 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.134 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.146 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 11.450 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.168 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.168 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.178 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.574 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.202 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.202 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.211 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.670 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.236 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.236 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.245 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 8.417 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.271 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.271 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.281 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.099 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.306 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.306 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.316 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.002 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.341 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.341 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.350 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.362 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.374 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.374 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.383 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 8.846 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.407 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.407 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.418 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.399 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.442 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.442 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.452 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.302 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.477 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.477 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.487 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.578 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.509 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.509 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.519 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.282 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.542 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.542 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.553 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 10.846 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.575 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.575 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.588 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 12.898 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.612 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.612 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.621 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.128 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.643 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.643 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.653 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.380 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.676 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.676 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.685 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 8.840 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.894 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.894 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.904 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 9.668 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.923 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.923 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.942 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 18.108 ms
2021-04-22 15:16:59.961 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10: SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=$1 ORDER BY time DESC
2021-04-22 15:16:59.961 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) DETTAGLI:  parametri: $1 = 'key001'
2021-04-22 15:16:59.961 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.086 ms
2021-04-22 15:17:00.195 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.005 ms
2021-04-22 15:17:00.195 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  esecuzione di S_1: COMMIT
2021-04-22 15:17:00.195 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.021 ms
```

Why is that? Is that due to some configuration I made, or PostgreSQL makes it multiple times in different threads, or the framework is actually sending it to PostgreSQL multiple times?

As an aside, how can I avoid logging lines like this one below, which are about queries that take less than `log_min_duration_statement`?

```
2021-04-22 15:17:00.195 CEST [19740] user@db (608173df.4d1c) LOG:  durata: 0.005 ms
```

Thanks, Alessio

Comment: What do you think `log_statement = 'all'` means?

Comment: I think it means both ddl and dml statements, subject to other conditions such as log_min_duration_statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You notice that there is only one

```
esecuzione di <unnamed>/C_10
```

followed by several

```
esecuzione di fetch da <unnamed>/C_10
```

So you obviously use a cursor and fetch the result set in pieces. Each of these fetches is a call to the server.